# What is the solution for the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y}{x}, y(-2) = -2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, mathematical-modeling

> Given $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{y}{x}, y(-2) = -2$
>
> I wish to solve for $y(x)$.

Separating the variables, I have,

$\dfrac{1}{y} dy = -\dfrac{1}{x} dx$

So

$\ln(|y|) = -\ln(|x|) + c$

So

$|y| = \exp({-\ln(|x|)+ c)}) = K \exp({\ln(\dfrac{1}{|x|})}) = K\dfrac{1}{|x|}$

At this step, I am unsure how to deal with the absolute value sign. Does anyone have idea as to how to proceed?

Comment: $|-2| = K\dfrac{1}{|-2|}$ so $K=4$ and $y = \dfrac{4}{x}$ is particular solution.

Comment: You can absorb the absolute value into the constant since $|x|=\pm x$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I think I understand you. Essentially, $|yx| = K \implies yx = \pm K = C$ and go from there. But still does it really make sense to equate $\pm K = C$? It seems I am setting two things into one thing.

Comment: @Nosrati Okay...but why did you drop the absolute value sign?

Comment: you have $y=\pm4/x$ and only $y=4/x$ passes from initial point.

Comment: @Nosrati Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can solve it without absolute value
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{y}{x}, y(-2) = -2$$
$$y'x+y=0$$
$$(xy)'= 0\implies xy=K \implies K=4$$
Therefore 
$$y=\frac 4x$$

Answer (score 1):

Per comment,

$\dfrac{1}{y} dy = -\dfrac{1}{x} dx$

So

$\ln(|y|) = -\ln(|x|) + c$

So

$|y| = \exp({-\ln(|x|)+ c)}) = K \exp({\ln(\dfrac{1}{|x|})}) = K\dfrac{1}{|x|}$

$|yx| = K \implies yx = \pm K$

At initial condition, $(-2)(-2) = \pm K \implies K = \pm 4$

Therefore, $y = \pm 4\dfrac{1}{x}$

But since the only solution that passes through $y(-2) = -2$ is $y = 4 \dfrac{1}{x}$, therefore, it is the solution of this ODE.

Is this correct? Seems I am still off.

Comment: Correct to me!.

Comment: @Nosrati The problem is that, the moment I provide the initial condition, I should obtain only one solution. However, I still got two solutions. And the only way I obtained the unique solution is by applying the IC again, which feels off.

Comment: We reject $y = -4\dfrac{1}{x}$, since doesn't pass $(-2,-2)$. so we have one solution.